# Where is my Displacement Map?

Tags: mesh, texturing

[image]
My displacement map seems to have disappeared...anyone know why?

Comment: Hello and welcome, you need to explain more about your issue in order to understand your question

Comment: Without any further information on what you did, how should we know what happened to your displacement map? Apart from that, a displacement map usually is a texture, the part of the settings you are showing in the screenshot holds no information about textures. Or do you mean the settings how to handle displacement (_Bump Only_, _Displacement Only_, _Displacement & Bump_)? They are only available for _Cycles_, you have set the render engine to _EEVEE_.

Answer (score 2):

The *Displacement* settings are only available in Cycles render engine, for the moment you are in Eevee.